# Combine and use arithmetic on SQL values from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

1. I have a table with data of guests to an event. I can retrieve the number of people who have attended (`membersAttended`) with this query:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.`name1`) AS `membersAttended`
       FROM `tmc_doorapp_guests` g
       LEFT JOIN `tmc_doorapp_events` e
       ON e.`id` = g.`event_id`
       WHERE `name1` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
       AND e.`date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
       AND g.`checkin` = 1;
   ```
2. To retrieve the total number of members (`totalMembers`) I use:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) AS `totalMembers`
       FROM `tmc_users`;
   ```
3. To get a **percentage value** (`totalPercent`) of members who have attended across the total members, I use PHP to make the two queries and then calculate like so:

   ```
   $totalPercent = number_format(($membersAttended/$totalMembers*100),2);
   ```

---

I've tried combining the two queries and the percentage calculation in a similar way to below, with no luck:

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.`name1`) AS `membersAttended`,
        COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`) AS `totalMembers`,
        (`membersAttended` * 100 / `totalMembers`) AS `totalPercent`
        FROM `tmc_doorapp_guests` g, `tmc_users` m
        LEFT JOIN `tmc_doorapp_events` e
        ON e.`id` = g.`event_id`
        WHERE `name1` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
        AND e.`date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        AND g.`checkin` = 1;
```

I also tried expanding out the columns:

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.`name1`) AS `membersAttended`,
        COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`) AS `totalMembers`,
        (COUNT(DISTINCT g.`name1`) * 100 / COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`)) AS `totalPercent`
        FROM `tmc_doorapp_guests` g, `tmc_users` m
        LEFT JOIN `tmc_doorapp_events` e
        ON e.`id` = g.`event_id`
        WHERE `name1` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
        AND e.`date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        AND g.`checkin` = 1;
```

This gives me the error:

> Error code: 1054. Unknown column 'g.event_id' in 'on clause'

**How can I combine these SQL/PHP queries/calculations into one SQL query?**

Comment: Swap `tmc_doorapp_guests g, tmc_users m` in order to have proper JOIN, i.e.: `tmc_users m, tmc_doorapp_guests g`

Comment: @mitkosoft This has worked! Add this as an answer and I'll accept. Why is this the case?

Comment: it's coming from SQL strict mode in order to follow strict (i.e. proper) syntax in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.`name1`) AS `membersAttended`,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) FROM `tmc_users`) AS `totalMembers`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT g.`name1`) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `id`)
                                          FROM `tmc_users`) AS `totalPercent`
FROM `tmc_doorapp_guests` g
LEFT JOIN `tmc_doorapp_events` e
ON e.`id` = g.`event_id`
WHERE `name1` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
AND e.`date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND g.`checkin` = 1;
```